# Generating a Symmetric DES Key in java

Tags: java

I wanna generate a DES key i java , This is the code:

```
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class Deskey {

      public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        // Generate a DES key
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();

      }
    }
```

I get the error " The value of local variable p is not used".

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning at most, but your code doesn't have a variable `p`, so you're compiling something else instead of the code you're showing.

Comment: You shouldn't use DES for anything modern. It's not considered secure anymore.

Comment: You shouldn't use DES in new work, use AES, it is as easy to use and secure.